# Python / Django - Mypy: expression has type "Type[ModelInstance]", variable has type "ModelInstance"

Tags: python, django, mypy

I'm working on a Django app that provides a GraphQL api for the frontend. I'm using mypy for typechecking and when running mypy I'm encountering errors that I do not understand

When running I get the following errors:

```
api/schema.py:50: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[Academy]", variable has type "Academy")
api/schema.py:57: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[School]", variable has type "School")
api/schema.py:64: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[AcademyGroup]", variable has type "AcademyGroup")
```

This is the code that mypy is checking

```
class AcademyType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model: Academy = Academy
        filter_fields: List[str] = ['name', 'domain', 'slug']
        interfaces: Tuple = (relay.Node,)


class SchoolType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model: School = School
        filter_fields: List[str] = ['name', 'academy']
        interfaces: Tuple = (relay.Node,)


class AcademyGroupType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model: AcademyGroup = AcademyGroup
        filter_fields: List[str] = ['name', 'academy']
        interfaces: Tuple = (relay.Node,)
```

So the lines that keep failing are variants on `model: AcademyGroup = AcademyGroup`, but that is just a 'Django model as type' definition that is happening all over my code (and does not seem to be generating errors)

As such I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the type of `model` is not `School`, but `Type` (or `Type[School]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of your `model` attributes is not the class itself, but a `Type`. Indeed, if you say `model = Academy`, then the type of `model` is `type(model) == type(Academy) == Type`, indeed, `Academy` is *not* an `Academy` *object*, it is a reference to the class, the type of such class is a (subclass) of `Type`. You can furthermore use [**`Type[…]`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) to specify the (base-)class of the type, so `Type[C]` means it is a type that is `C`, or a subclass of `C`:

You thus should annotate it as:

```
from typing import Type

class AcademyType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model: Type[Academy] = Academy
        filter_fields: List[str] = ['name', 'domain', 'slug']
        interfaces: Tuple = (relay.Node,)


class SchoolType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model: Type[School] = School
        filter_fields: List[str] = ['name', 'academy']
        interfaces: Tuple = (relay.Node,)


class AcademyGroupType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model: Type[AcademyGroup] = AcademyGroup
        filter_fields: List[str] = ['name', 'academy']
        interfaces: Tuple = (relay.Node,)
```